# Background image in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, image

How do you set a Background image in blender 2.8?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose of the background, but if you encounter this problem in 2.8, it means that you are confused by the loss of the sidebar, then you need a camera background

[image: camera background]